# Android XML weight gives width problems

Tags: android, xml

The problem is a little bit difficult to explain, so i will use the pictures: 
[image: this is what i want]

This is how i want it to look, but at the moment none of the editboxes have a `layout_width`. When I add a `layout_width` (no matter which type) the following happens:

[image: with width]

What causes this? How can i get it to look like the first image, but keep the width (can't start the app if there is no `layout_width`? Oh and I want to avoid using specific units, because it looks crap on bigger devices, or at least i think it does (I have a Galaxy Note)
Here is my code, specifically for the radiogroup and edittexts (the button is in the main layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="100" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/X1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_weight="20" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="10" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" 
        android:singleLine="true">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

<EditText android:layout_weight="20"
    android:id="@+id/Y1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:ems="10" android:gravity="center" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" 
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_weight="20" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/plus" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" android:text="+"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/minus" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center" android:text="-"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/multiply" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" android:text="*"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/div" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:text="/"/>
</RadioGroup>

<EditText android:id="@+id/X2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="20" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/Y2" 
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:gravity="right" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you set the what ever axis you want to be weighted to 0dp.

In your case set layoutWidth to 0dp

this should keep them all the same.

Comment: worked thanks, will accept as answer, when the site allows me :)

Comment: it worked and looks fine within eclipse, but when i run the emulator it displays it like in the second image. help? :\

Comment: You might need to remove the ems value as well since I think it is forcing a width.